# php json_decode into array

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

I have my json being passed to the php file as follows.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 $.ajax({
      url: "/gallerytest/getimages.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
           imagesArray: imageArray.itemList,
           action: "load"
      },
      success: function(imagesArray) {
             for (var i = 0; i < imagesArray.length; i++) {
                  console.log('image ' + imagesArray[i]["src"]);
             }
      }
  });
```

With the imagesArray being captured in the php file, I want to put it into an array. In my php I have this so far:

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
$action = $_POST['action'];
switch($action) {
    case "test" : test();break;
    case "load" : load();break;
    // ...etc...
}
}


function load(){

$imagesArray = $_POST['imagesArray'];


$images = json_decode($imagesArray, true);
$imagesArr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($images); $i++){
    $image = array(
        "src" => $images[$i]
    );
    $imagesArr[] = $image;  
}


echo json_encode($imagesArr);
}
```

I am passing the array back for testing purposes where the javascript outputs the src of each element.

The ultimate goal which I would like help on too, should it not go beyond the call of duty, is in an SQL statement capture more images where the src does not match. 
In essence:

```
 SELECT * FROM images WHERE id_image NOT IN (imagesArray) ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 12
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition (an example for PDO) I'm sure similar posts exists for mysqli_*

Comment: What exactly is the problem? you got some error? is it returning wrong data? btw is it echo `json_encode($imagesArray);`? Should it not be `echo json_encode($imagesArr);`?

Comment: It doesn't echo anything. I have a test method that just spits out a list of numbers so I think the problem is converting the json object into a php array.

Comment: You are encoding the wrong variable..

Comment: `for($i = 0; $i < count($images); $i++) {` change the for loop, most likely a 500 error and always check the response code from the console browser. and `echo json_encode($imagesArr);`

Comment: no console isn't throwing any errors. It logs the "load images" in the JS section okay. I have a test method which creates an empty array, loops around filling it with numbers 1..10 and then passes it back to JS. That console.logs fine. So I assume the issue lies in the decode part or somewhere in the JSON php object part. @kevinabelita the for loop is the same as you've suggested :S.

Comment: @user3012749 you could just echos after every step to debug it. Did you repair the for cycle bug kevinabelita found? Is the `success` event in js even fired? Try to add `error` event too

Comment: That's what I assume. It should print at the very least 'image null' or along those lines. I thought the echo at that point will be a good time to debug. Not many steps before that. I have fixed the for loop but still an error

Comment: @Uriel_SVK parsererror 
SyntaxError {stack: (...), message: "Unexpected token <"}(arguments),b?e=h.length:c&&(g=d,j(c))}return this}

Comment: @user3012749 looks like some jQuery error, can you add breakpoints in `success`/`error` events in js to see what exactly is causing it?

Comment: unfortunately not. I've decided to get the imagesArray `$imagesArray = $_POST['imagesArray'];` then echo back `echo $imagesArray;`

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
      url: "/gallerytest/getimages.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
           "imagesArray": imageArray.itemList,
           "action": "load"
      },
      success: function(imagesArray) {
             for (var i = 0; i < imagesArray.length; i++) {
                  console.log('image ' + imagesArray[i]["src"]);
             }
      }
  });
```

Please Pass the **action** and **imagesArray** tag in double quote